# controlling ClickOnce updates

Tags: clickonce

Justification for this question: Looked through 15 pages of ClickOnce articles, did internet searches as well. However the keywords contained in this question keep fouling the searches.

We have an application that has been deployed using clickonce for several years. We now have a new requirement: no updates are to be made available to clients unless they have a current maintenance contract with our company.

The only control we currently have over ClickOnce is to check for updates upon program start. We've created a datastore (XML) of matching serial numbers and maintenance contract expiry dates. The logic seems straightforward enough: if your expiry date is in the past, then you don't get the update. But this type of process seems to require control outside of the Clickonce update itself.

Any ideas on how we can implement this? We'd prefer to do it inside the application if possible, but something like a web service is an option.

Thanks in advance for any good suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to stop using automatic updates and [switch to manual updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx). This will allow you to have custom code that checks the maintenance contract first and then can conditionally perform the update.